# Deprecated: Function sql_regcase() is deprecated in Gpf.class.php on line 97

Tags: php

I face this problem and find a way to fixed this... but I can't find a way..

I face this problem on line no 97 ..

Here is my line no 97 ...

```
 $filename = $pathPrefix . sql_regcase(self::getRelativeClassPath($className)). '.class.php';
```

I also find this.. http://matrixdebug.blogspot.com/2012/10/deprecated-function-sqlregcase-is.html but can't understand what can I do?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to the use of depreciated function. `sql_regcase()` was deprecated in PHP V5.3.0 and shouldn't be used any longer

Comment: you need to find another function or change the version ..thats the only solution